# How to add particular ffmpeg sources into config?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

I have my ffmpeg confix. For example:

```
./configure \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=armv7s \
--cc='xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang' \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv7s -mios-version-min=7.0' \
--extra-cxxflags='-arch armv7s -mios-version-min=7.0' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7s -mios-version-min=7.0' \
--prefix=armv7s \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-doc \
--disable-shared \
--disable-everything \
--enable-static \
--enable-pic \
--disable-muxers \
--enable-muxer=flv \
--disable-demuxers \
--enable-demuxer=h264 \
--disable-parsers \
--enable-parser=h264 \
```

But in addition I need to use also other code from ffmpeg library like `#include "libavcodec/golomb.h"`. How to add these particular sources to the config or where can I find which sources can I include with which config setting?

Comment: after running make install it should install the .h files to "armv7s/include" so you should be able to include them from there

Comment: But I also need to some particular .c sources to be compiled in due library.

Comment: which .c sources? are you referring to c sources in the ffmpeg source?

Comment: Actually now I've found out, that I don't need to. But in case of need - Yes, sources in the ffmpeg.